# Sanitize AROUND shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode, tinymce

I have a [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/checklist/) which allows users to mark a bullet list and then add a shortcode around it. Unfortunately, when users select the bullet list, the first UL is not selected and therefore they end up with a weird selection. The end code should be:

```
[checklist-box title="Hello"]
<ul>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>yyyy</li>
    <li>zzz</li>
</ul>
[/checklist-box]
```

but instead ends up as something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>[checklist-box title="Hello"]
<ul>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>yyyy</li>
    <li>zzz</li>
</ul>
[/checklist-box]</li>
</ul>
```

which looks horrible.

Clarify: I need the [checklist-box] shortcode to wrap the whole list including the

This is the code that wraps the bullets in TinyMCE:

```
onsubmit: function(e) {
      var selected_text = editor.selection.getContent();
      shortcode = '[checklist-box title="' + e.data.title + '"]' + selected_text + '[/checklist-box]';
      editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);
}
```

Comment: not sure what is exactly the question here. if the code of the plugin is relevant to the question, please edit the question and include the relevant parts. As it is right now it is a question that better asked in a tinymce forum.

Comment: The question is how to ensure the selected text is wrapping any UL tags so that the HTML produced is not messy

Comment: ... therefor it is a tinymce question? the fact that you try to insert ashortcode has zero to do with your problem

Comment: this is a WP question. Please be productive and not badger other people.

Comment: seriously? you engage in pointless argument about where is best to ask the question, and complain that other people are not productive? lol it is your time you are wasting

Comment: I have a problem on Wordpress so this is a WP issue. You can even read the comment from dbeja below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```
editor.focus();
var selected_text = editor.selection.getContent();
shortcode = '[checklist-box title="' + e.data.title + '"]' + selected_text + '[/checklist-box]';
editor.selection.setContent(shortcode);
editor.setContent(editor.getContent());
```

Basically, I'm first forcing editor focus and then use setContent instead to change the content. In my tests there were still some glitches on the editor but the source was ok, so I just copy all content and set it again to refresh the editor.

Comment: Sorry but this yields the same result. Mixed html as in my questions.

Comment: It worked directly with TinyMCE, but now I tried inside WP and doesn't work. Selections on browsers/wysiwyg editors are always a nightmare... maybe it's related to TinyMCE on WP being inside an iframe, I don't know. But after you apply the shortcode, if you toggle between HTML and back to Editor tabs it looks fine on my side. the only think I would suggest would be to try to replicate that behaviour, but doesn't look very "clean"...